# How can I use custom navigation buttons in swiperjs with content that updates onClick?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm struggling with the docs for swiperjs. I'm trying to create custom navigation buttons that swipe content (or the slide) vertically and load the next slide of (prefetched) data from slice.items:

```
<Swiper
      navigation={{
        prevEl: CarouselButton,
        nextEl: CarouselButton
      }}
      direction='vertical'
      modules={[Navigation]}   
    >
      {slice?.items.map((item, index) =>
        <SwiperSlide key={item.unique_id} className='swiper-slide'>
          <div>
            <CustomNavButton>{item.answer_field_1}</CarouselButton>
            <CustomNavButton>{item.answer_field_2}</CarouselButton>
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>)
      }
    </Swiper>
```

Any ideas what swiper APIs I should be using to achieve a slide onClick?

Comment: Hi. Your Q not clear. Maybe add a screenshot of your idea.

Comment: Here's an example, without swiperjs: https://codepen.io/Schepp/pen/WNbQByE